# Redirect all url from folder to root but keep folder unchanged

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website and want to permanently change the url structure from:

```
www.mysite.com/blog/post-name/

www.mysite.com/post-name/
```

I found a solution:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]/
```

The only thing is I want to be able to keep `www.mysite.com/blog/` as a page without it redirecting to `www.mysite.com/`

Can't figure this one out.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps by changing the [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)? `^blog/(.+)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ $1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteRule ^((?!blog/).*)$ /blog/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `R=301` from the rewrite rule should fix that.
The rule would be:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L]
```